# get json data from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I am trying to access json data sent from python script. In my python script I am sending data to my Ajax success function in the following format:

```
def main():
"""Create instance of FieldStorage""" 
dat = cgi.FieldStorage( keep_blank_values = True ) 

Start_date = "07/01/2013"
dc = ['las','sjc']
sys = "All"



result = [{"startdate":Start_date,"datacenter":dc,"system":sys}]

res = json.dumps(result)

print res
```

Now in the javascript I am trying to access the individual values of my Json but I get a message saying "undefined" in console.log. But the data is printing correctly, I am not able to access individual objects of my JSON.

```
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '/cgi-bin/worlddata.py',
                    data: $(form).serialize(),


                    success: function(data, status) {


                      var response = JSON.parse(data);
                      console.log("THe json is "+response.datacenter); //prints undefined
                      console.log("result is "+data); // prints result is [{"startdate": "07/01/2013", "system": "All", "datacenter": ["las", "sjc"]}]

                      console.log("The status is "+status); // prints The status is success
                      console.log(data.datacenter); // prints undefined
```

My question how to access response.message or data.message? Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect any of those objects to have a `message` property? Also, is `data` a string or a JSON object?

Comment: Sorry, that was by mistake. I changed the variable names now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are serializing an array containing an object; on the python side [] is superfluous. Remove them and then in javascript you can access the values as result.system, result.startdate and result.datacenter

```
result = {"startdate": Start_date,"datacenter": dc,"system": sys}
print json.dumps(result)
```

And then

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
console.log("The json startdate is " + response.startdate); //prints undefined
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works, guess I was making a silly error there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's getJSON function.

```
$.getJSON('/cgi-bin/worlddata.py', {
    $(form).serialize()
}).success(data, status) {
   success stuff goes here
});
```

Also, if you want to use ajax I believe you have to set dataType: "json" as well.